# Creating subaddresses

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am using Ledger with the Monero GUI wallet. I have recieved XMR and it works fine. I wonder if it is possible to create a subaddress to receive new XMR and if so how?

Many thanks,
Mikael

Answer (score 0):

In the "Receive" section, "Create new address".